# Upload file trouble in PHP

Tags: php, file, image-uploading

I have made an upload image a couple times before and I never have problems. And I just copy the script and it worked fine, but after I copy I don't know why it keep shows that I'm not using the right extension. Can you spot the mistake?

This is the form script:

```
<tr height="30">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right">Gambar Barang &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="gambar" /></td>
</tr>
```

and its the action,

```
$errors= array();
$uploaddir = 'images/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['gambar']['name']);
$gambar      = $_FILES['gambar']['name'];
$gambar_size     = $_FILES['gambar']['size'];
$gambar_type     = $_FILES['gambar']['type'];
$gambar_tmp      = $_FILES['gambar']['tmp_name'];
$gambar_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['gambar']['name'])));

 $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

  if(in_array($gambar_ext,$expensions)=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }

  if($gambar_size > 4097152){
     $errors[]='File size must be excately 4 MB';
  }

  if(empty($errors)==true){
     copy($_FILES['gambar']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);

  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things that could cause file upload to fail:

- does the upload form have enctype="multipart/form-data"?
- is file_uploads = On in php.ini?
- what is the max post/upload limit in php.ini?
- did you check the permissions for the upload folder?

Comment: the form has the enctype="multipart/form-data", the file_uploads is on, and i think there is no problem with the permission for the upload folder. but, i kinda confused on how to check the max post/upload, but i do find the memory_limit is 256M and the upload_max_filesize is 4M

Comment: He was talking about upload max file size

Comment: Also try echo $gambar_ext; to see if you're comparing the right part, p.s. just check chmod of directory its folder permissions you can see in FTP as folder properties, also you could try to check the value of in_array($gambar_ext,$expensions)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, just make sure your form uses:

method='post'

and(as already mentioned by Reto) - enctype="multipart/form-data"

i.e. something along the lines of:

```html
<form method='post' action='#' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Comment: oh yeah my bad, i was checking the enctype but its in the wrong form.. i'm very sorry, and thanks for the reminder